# What is this tool that's shown here?

Tags: mesh

In the gif below it shows the mesh being pulled upwards with a circle tool and all the faces/verts form a nice smooth curved surface. How do i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Blender Proportional Edit.
You may search with this term.

Comment: .. and before proportional edit, in this gif, Grid Fill.

Comment: The shortcut key is: O.